# Haskell - what is a deprecated function

Tags: haskell

I'm using `splitEvery` in my Haskell code importing `Data.List.Split.Internals`. For every time I use `splitEvery` I get the following warning:

```
In the use of `splitEvery`
(imported from Data.List.Split.Internals):
Deprecated: "Use chunksOf."
```

If I use `chunksOf` instead of `splitEvery` I get no warnings. Does anyone know the reason? (To note I only used `splitEvery`as I came across it first.

Comment: You should probably change your question and ask "what is a deprecated function" to avert downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning says `splitEvery` is deprecated. Probably, `splitEvery` is going to be removed in future versions of the library, so the library author is advising you not to use it, and use `chunksOf` instead.

As a general guideline, modules ending with `....Internal` are not meant to be imported directly by library users. The interface of such modules is very unstable: the author will feel free to change it at every whim.

Update: as Zeta says below, `splitEvery` *is* already removed from the current library.

Comment: Sorry, rollback: it's still there, but not documented anymore: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/src/Data-List-Split-Internals.html#splitEvery. But as you said, it's likely to get removed in the next `0.x` version.

Comment: Thank you for both of your answers, I understand now.